# Bash wrapper script spawning multiple children

Tags: shell-script

I made a wrapper around ffmpeg, to modify calls from my software without having to change source code.

However when I use it, it seems to keep spawning children doing the same command. Like If my software were calling it multiple times.

I don't know what could cause this behavior? It doesn't happen when the software calls ffmpeg directly.

This happens even if there is no modification at all, with exec or without.

```
#!/bin/bash

# command="$(echo $@ | awk '{gsub("warning","error"); print}')"

exec /usr/bin/ffmpeg.bak "$@"
```

I made /usr/bin/ffmpeg to be this script, that then forwards to ffmpeg.bak which is the real ffmpeg binary.

No matter what I try, the behavior of spawning multiple processes for the same command happens. Any ideas?

Maybe this happens because the software keeps track of it, probably by using PID and stuff, and this confuses it.

So I need to do this as transparent as possible

Comment: Your script is executable, isn't it (`chmod a+rx /usr/bin/ffmpeg`)

Comment: maybe try running `ffmpeg.bak` without `exec`.  That way, the shell script won't exit until `ffmpeg.bak` finishes, which sounds like it's significant to the calling program (probably waiting for ffmpeg's output file to exist).    BTW, your script doesn't use any bash-specific features, so it would be slightly faster to use `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/dash` if sh is a symlink to bash on your system. sh is smaller and simpler with less startup overhead.

Comment: I have tried all possible combinations, but nothing seems to make this 100% transparent to my software. It seems to not recognize that ffmpeg is running, or see the right pid, and then keep calling it again

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the script that you've posted. I've used this technique in the past to wrap other commands.

You could try adding this command immediately above the `exec` line, which on my Debian-based systems would log the call to `/var/log/user.log` (among others)

```
logger -t ffmpeg "$*"
```

You can then confirm how many times it's being called, and with what arguments.

---

It's been suggested that the calling process is seeing the PID of the shell script disappear and assuming it has exited unexpectedly. I am not convinced this is the reason. Here's my demonstration scenario with a script, called `/tmp/exec.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
tty=$(tty)
echo "tty is $tty, pid is $$"

# Identify processes running on this terminal
echo "Processes running on this terminal (1)"
ps -ft "${tty#/dev/}"

# Prepare to identify processes running on this terminal after the shell
# script has been replaced with another command
(
    sleep 3
    echo "Processes running on this terminal (2)"
    ps -ft "${tty#/dev/}"
) &

# Replace the shell script with another command
exec sleep 7

# Ooops
echo exec failed
exit 1
```

Example run, with annotations

```
chmod a+rx /tmp/exec.sh
/tmp/exec.sh

tty is /dev/pts/3, pid is 17550
Processes running on this terminal (1)
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
roaima   29123 29121  0 22:10 pts/3    00:00:01 /bin/bash
roaima   17550 29123  0 22:13 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash /tmp/exec.sh
roaima   17552 17550  0 22:13 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -ft pts/3
```

You can see here (above) that the shell script PID is 17550, running from an interactive session with PID 29123.

```
Processes running on this terminal (2)
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
roaima   29123 29121  0 22:10 pts/3    00:00:01 /bin/bash
roaima   17550 29123  0 22:13 pts/3    00:00:00 sleep 7
roaima   17553 17550  0 22:13 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash /tmp/exec.sh
roaima   17555 17553  0 22:13 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -ft pts/3
```

What has happened now is that the shell script PID 17550 has been replaced with the `sleep` command. (The PID 17553 is the subshell we kicked off to report on processes running on this terminal.)

Comment: I think the issue is that the PID my software see is not the actual PID of the process running ffmpeg, even with using exec. I also tried to run without exec, add exit 0, add &, I have tried so many combinations and nothing works. My software keeps calling ffmpeg and ffmpeg again because I think it believes it's not running or exited on error

Comment: @Freedo I don't think it's a premature exit. See my updated answer for an example demonstrating why (not)